# Flutter SlideTransition from 0.9 percent of screen

Tags: flutter, dart

Here i wrote a simple code to show a container with `SlideTransition` animation. in this code i try to slide the container from `0.9` of screen from bottom but in this code animation started from zero, that means i can't limit this slide animation

for example you suppose i have a `Container` with 400 height and i want to slide the container from 300 to 400. but i can't

```dart
class ChannelDetailRouter extends PageRoute<void> {
  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  ChannelDetailRouter({required this.builder, RouteSettings? settings}) : super(settings: settings);

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  Color? get barrierColor => null;

  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap:()=>Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        child: SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(0, 0.9),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation,
            curve: Curves.easeIn,
          )),
          child: builder(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 350);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were very close to the answer just change

```
begin: const Offset(0, 0.9),
```

to

```
begin: const Offset(0, 0.1),
```